# Sequence contains more than one element Mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

**Problem function**
Below is the function that i'm having issues with. I keep getting the "sequence contains more than one element" error. Which it is suppose to. However, i'm unsure how to return the information so i can use it. Any help would be appreciated.

The `EditCountyViewModel` is a small class that contains `public County county`public List CountyList`. I have also tried changing the Read<> to`Read` which is just the base class for all of my county information.

```
public EditCountyViewModel FindByCounty(string countyName)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@CountyName", value: countyName);

            var query = @"SELECT counties.id
                            , counties.CountyName
                            , counties.Website
                            , counties.Address
                            , counties.City
                            , counties.State
                            , counties.PhonePrimary
                            , counties.PhoneAlt
                            , counties.RecordsOnline
                            , counties.BackToYear
                            , counties.Cost
                            , products.ProductName
                            , products.Description
                            , countyproduct.TurnTime_MinHours
                            , countyproduct.TurnTime_MaxHours
                            , countyproduct.Price
                        FROM
                            counties, countyproduct, products
                        WHERE
                            counties.CountyName = @CountyName AND countyproduct.countiesID = countyproduct.countiesID AND countyproduct.productsID = products.ID;";

            //using (var multi = this.db.QueryMultipl(query, new { countyName }))
            //{
            //    EditCountyViewModel editVM = new EditCountyViewModel();
            //    editVM.county = multi.Read<County>().Single();
            //    return editVM;
            //}
            return this.db.Query<EditCountyViewModel>(query, parameters).SingleOrDefault();

        }
```

I think i need another class to handle the items coming from the `countyproduct`  & `products` table.

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: the return line. But in the commented out code, the `editVM.county = multi.Read<County>().Single();` gives me the error

Comment: the sql looks funny. countyproduct.countiesID = countyproduct.countiesID is that intended?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault()` makes sure there is only 1 record returned and will throw if there are more. Use `FirstOrDefault()` if you just want to grab the first one.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the correct answer. If you expect more than one element, do not use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`. If you only want the first, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.